# Check if a string is any of multiple items

Tags: ruby

I have a string

```
x = "student"
```

how do I check if "x" matches any of the items in a list of names that I have. The names are a fixed list.

```
names = ["teacher", 
         "parent", 
         "son", 
         "daughter", 
         "friend", 
         "classmate", 
         "principal", 
         "vice-principal", 
         "student", 
         "graduate"]
```

I tried setting names as a list and using any? to check the list but that seems to only work for an array and I have a string.

I am using Ruby 2.2.1 Also I only need it to return true or false if the item is in the list

Comment: What do you mean by *I have a string*? `names` is an array!

Comment: @spickermann My object is the string which is passed into my method. The array is fixed and does not change. So I was looking at it from the view of here is a string and let me match it to any item in this array instead of here is my array, let me see if the string is included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
names.include?(your_string)
```

If the string is inside the array it will return true

Comment: Thanks that got it! I was looking at it from the string matching the array instead of the array including the string. DUH! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the include? method on array like so:

```
if names.include? x do
  # x is an element in the list
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use grep for finding string is present in an array or not

```
names = ["teacher", 
         "parent", 
         "son", 
         "daughter", 
         "friend", 
         "classmate", 
         "principal", 
         "vice-principal", 
         "student", 
         "graduate"]

names.grep(/^daughter$/)
```

Answer (score 0):

What if your `names` array contains multiple instances of `x`? Then assuming you're not after a boolean you could use [`Enumerable#count`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) where we pass the condition required within a code block. In your example we would have:

```
names.count{ |i| i == x } #=> 1
```

*Another example:*

```
x = "student"
names = ["student", "cleaner", "student"] 

names.count{ |i| i == x } #=> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way to do this:

```
if not (names & [x]).empty?
  puts "'#{x}' is present in names"
end
```